# Satellite and VPN access issues

Tags: security

My only internet access is by satellite and my company uses VPN. Is there any way to spoof my transmission to get around the distance time problem that sattilite has.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to spoof your IP address to reduce the latency - the latency exists due largely to the speed of light.

Ignoring that it won't fix the latency issue, Spoofing your IP address is not really practical because decent ISP's will block IP ranges from outside their networks. (Egress filtering)

[If you describe what your usage case is there may be workarounds/optimizations that could help you. Also, not all satellite systems have the same latency - Low Earth satellites have lower latency then typical geostationary ones, so it's conceivable you could find a network with better latency ]